# Move Branch to another folder on TFS - Branch Exists error

Tags: tfs, branch, branching-and-merging

I have a project setup with the folder structure underneath

```
Project
   Archive
      Source
   Development
      Source
```

I want to move some old branches under Development/Source to Archive/Source.  I can move it, however, when I try to commit the changes for the move, it states that the branch already exists.  I can view all deleted branches and I cant see anything in the archive folder which state that it already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting deleted branches into folders. Maybe that helps.